# Google Sheets - Hiding/Showing Rows based on Dropdown Selections

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, show-hide

I've got a sheet where I have a dropdown which will show or hide certain rows dependent on which dropdown value is chosen. I have the following script:

```
      var watchSheet = "Overview";
      var watchCell = "P1";
      
      var sheet = a.range.getSheet();
      if (sheet.getName() !== watchSheet ||
          a.range.getA1Notation() !== watchCell) {
        return;
      }
      
      switch (a.value) {
        case "Class 302 - Class 319":
          sheet.showRows(2, 35);
          sheet.hideRows(36, 189);
          break;
        case "Class 320 - Class 345":
          sheet.showRows(36, 64);
          sheet.hideRows(2, 35);
          sheet.hideRows(65, 189);
          break; 
        case "Class 350 - Class 379":
          sheet.showRows(64, 91);
          sheet.hideRows(2, 63);
          sheet.hideRows(92, 189);
          break; 
        case "Class 380 - Class 399":
          sheet.showRows(92, 112);
          sheet.hideRows(2, 91);
          sheet.hideRows(113, 189);
          break;    
        case "Class 403 - Class 438":
          sheet.showRows(114, 154);
          sheet.hideRows(2, 112);
          sheet.hideRows(155, 189);
          break;  
        case "Class 442 - Class 484":
          sheet.showRows(155, 182);
          sheet.hideRows(2, 154);
          sheet.hideRows(183, 300);
          break;          
        case "Show All":
          sheet.showRows(2, 300);  
        default:
      }  
    }
```

It works fine up to the selection "Class 380 - Class 399" but when I select "Class 403 - Class 438" it doesn't hide rows 155-189 and when I select "Class 442 - Class 484" nothing happens.

Have I over-egged this script and it is struggling to manage the amount of requests or is there something else that I am missing and can't see?

Comment: hideRows parameters are start position and number of rows not start and end.  You should consider making it an installable trigger because simple triggers must complete in 30 seconds

Comment: About `but when I select "Class 403 - Class 438" it doesn't hide rows 155-189`, in your script, rows 2-143 and 155-343 are hidden. If you want to hide rows 155-189, please test `sheet.hideRows(155, 35)`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex,-numrows) And, about `when I select "Class 442 - Class 484" nothing happens`, in this case, what do you want to do?

Comment: `because simple triggers must complete in 30 seconds` Ahh. You learn something every day. There are nine [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) for "simple triggers" - #7=`They cannot run for longer than 30 seconds.`